# Is it possible to get notified when the screensaver starts or stops under linux

Tags: c++, linux, gtk, glib, gio

I want to get notified when the screensaver (probably xscreensaver) starts or stops. Is there any solution with gtk, glib, gio or other library that will do that for me under linux?

Comment: Probabably read [EWMH](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html) then track some properties on the root X11 window

Comment: Should it be specifically the screensaver starting? Why not simply check for when your window has lost the focus and doesn't regain it for a long time?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the ActiveChanged signal in `org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver` D-Bus interface. It's supported by current GNOME and KDE at least (if you want to support older GNOME releases you may have to keep an eye on `org.gnome.ScreenSaver` as well).

Unfortunately the spec seems to have disappeared -- or it was ever in email form. Take a look with d-feet or something to see the actually available API (it's not too complex).